# replaceAll all characters in statement to new characters

Tags: java, android

i have EditText the user can write and statement

i need to replaceAll all characters to new characters .

this **arrayOfChar1** char array for ASCII code for all characters from a to z
i need to change all  characters user input in edittext to  all new characters from this array **arrayOfString1**
but i don't know how to replaceAll all characters

Example for input from user: "how are you"
the output : "нσω αяє yσυ"

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str2 = edit.getText().toString();
            char[] arrayOfChar1 = { 97, 98, 99, 100, 101};
            String[] arrayOfString1 = { "α", "в", "c",};

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.... Show us what you tried, the expected input, and the expected output, and simply, the purpose of your algorithm.

Comment: Your question is not clear. which characters do you want to replace with what and what is your expected output and what are the errors you getting after trying

Comment: OK , i edit my question and put example , i hope now clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A HashMap would be better suited for your task.

```
final static HashMap<Character, String> replacements = new HashMap<Character, String>() {{
    put('a', "α" );
    put('b', "в"); 
    put('c', "c");
    put('d', "ɒ");
    put('e', "є");
    // ...
}};
```

Code to translate

```
String str = "abbacde";
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
for (char c : chars) {
    String replacement = replacements.get(c);
    str = str.replaceAll(""+c, replacement);
}

System.out.println(str); // αввαcɒє
```

Comment: thank you but i have this error (cannot resolve symbol "replacements")
in this line     String replacement = replacements.get(c);
what should i do ?

Comment: You should define the HashMap just below the `class YourActivity`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to replace the instances of [x] in your string with [y] where x is the value in `arrayOfChar1` and y is the corresponding value in `arrayOfString1`. If this is the case, you will probably want to look into a Map.

```
HashMap<Character, Character> charMap = new HashMap<>();
charMap.put('α', 'a');
charMap.put('в', 'b');
// ... finish the rest
```

And then loop through the map

```
Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    Character newChar = pair.getKey();
    Character oldChar = pair.getValue();
    et.getEditable().toString().replace(oldChar, newChar);
    it.remove();
}
```

This is far more manageable than having separate arrays that correspond to one another. You can also create a Map that will allow you to map to multiple characters (eg 'a' and 'A' to 'α').